# I'm trying to read pdf one by one and then converting it into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, pathlib, pymupdf

I've used 'fitz' from Pymupdf module to extract data and then with pandas converting the extracted data to dataframe.

#Code to read multiple pdfs from the folder:

```
from pathlib import Path
# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
pdf_search = Path("path").glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list

pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
```

#Code to extract the data:

```
for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        pypdf_text = ""
        for page in doc:
            pypdf_text += page.getText()
```

**But, the above code is only extracting the data for last pdf in the folder. and thus giving the result for only that pdf**
Although, the desired goal is to extract the data from all the pdfs in the folder one by one

Please help me understand and resolved why is this happening??

Comment: Define `pypdf_text` before `for pdf in pdf_files` loop. You rewrite it with empty string each time so lose text from previous pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code:

```
Path("path").glob("*.pdf")
```

to

```
files_pdf = [ file for file in glob.glob(path+"\*.pdf",recursive=True)]
```

and give path as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me,

```
from pathlib import Path
# returns all file paths that has .pdf as extension in the specified directory
pdf_search = Path("path").glob("*.pdf")
# convert the glob generator out put to list

pdf_files = pdf_files = [str(file.absolute()) for file in pdf_search]
```

#Code to extract the data:

```
pdf_txt = ""
for pdf in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(pdf) as doc:
        
        for page in doc:
            pdf_txt += page.getText()
```

#Converting the extracted data to data frame:

```
with open('pdf_txt.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as f: #Converting to text file
    f.write(pdf_txt)

data=pd.read_table('pdf_txt.txt',sep='\n')  #Converting text file to dataframe
```

Thank you @Yevhen Kuzmovych for your help!